# How can i edit and redesign my old embed messages

Tags: discord, discord.py

ive been texted something on my discord server before as embed. and now i just wanted to edit my old embed messages to redesign how its look by rewrite something and change colors.
how can i edit a specific embed messages by message id? i know it can edit itself by using :

```
first_embed = Embed(title='embed 1')
new_embed = Embed(title='embed 2')

msg = await ctx.send(embed=first_embed)
await msg.edit(embed=new_embed)
```

but i don't really know how to make it works. how it can edit at message ids? like checking its own id?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if I understand your question correctly, but to edit messages you could fetch them like this:

```py
message = await ctx.fetch_message(message ID)
```

Or you can just use the integrated message converter in the arguments of the command.

```py
@bot.command()
async def edit_embed(ctx, message: discord.Message):
    #define the new embed here
    await message.edit(embed=new_embed)
```

The user has to supply the message ID or message URL directly as an argument and discord.py will automatically convert it to a message object. Keep in mind that if you use the message ID, you will have to use the command in the same channel as the message you want to edit.

Comment: i can put message id in 'ctx.fetch_message' and write a new one. then i can use this command to make it edit itself right?

Comment: Sorry I'm still unsure what exactly you want to do. Do you want to send the embed and then edit it in the same command? Or send the embed in one command and then edit it later with a different command?

Comment: it says at 'message = await ctx.fetch_message(message ID)'. SyntaxError: 'await' outside function.

Comment: Were you trying to use this outside of a command? Also you are supposed to replace `message ID` with your actual message ID that you want to get

Comment: yes i did. this shown up when i use it outside. but when i used it inside the command it gave me 'TypeError: edit{} takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given'

Comment: Please take time and try to understand what this error message tells you. It says the error is caused by `edit` and that you gave it too many arguments. What does your `edit` statement look like? Also make sure to read the docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a new command to edit embeds and get the embed message's ID and the stuff you want to change as parameters. Then you can to [`Embed.copy()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Embed.copy) or [`Embed.to_dict()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Embed.to_dict) to get embed's data and then update the data you got as parameter.

### An example would be:

```py
@bot.command()
async def editembed(ctx, channel: discord.Chanel, msg_id, title, color):
    msg = await channel.fetch_message(msg_id)
    embed = msg.embeds[0].to_dict()
    embed["title"] = title
    embed["color"] = color
    await msg.edit(embed = discord.Embed.from_dict())
```

***Note:*** *bot has no fetch message attribute so you have to either get it from channel or context (while using context you have to send the command on the same channel as the message to be edited)*